# Changing boolean status with Model ID input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm creating an app where I need to check kids in. I'm stuck on a particular section, which I'm sure is really easy. Might just be overthinking it.

I have a page with an input field and a submit button. I want to be able to input a kid's ID and on submit I want the database column, "status", to be changed to either true or false (depending on what is it).

Just looking for some tips to get me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!
LP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ActiveRecord callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

For example you can define a **before_save** or **before_create** callback like this:

```
before_create :load_status

private
  def load_status
    self.status = !self.identifier.blank? #self.identifier is the kid's ID
  end
```

So, if kid's ID has some value the status attribute will be true

Comment: Wouldn't this just assign the "status" as true on its initial creation?

Comment: It's an example only. You can do whatever you want. I don't know the condition necessary to set status attribute on true or false.

Comment: I would enter the ID of the kid into a input field and on submit, it would update the "status" column.

Comment: Don't thank me, if it's the right answer, please accept the answer :P